# htaccess directoryindex redirect looking for css wrong place

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, directoryindex

Hello in my htaccesss file i put this code to ensure that my directory index file is set to

v2013/index.html

so i put this code

```
DirectoryIndex v2013/index.html
```

Then i Want it to look like mydomain.com/Welcome, so i add..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Welcome$ v2013/index.html [L]
```

My question is why DirectoryIndex not working anymore.. and how can i tell the browser to look for the css inside v2013, because is looking in the root. ( i think because of rewrite)  SO MY PAGE IS UNSTYLE.. =(

In other words is looking for www.domain.com/css/sheet.css insted of

www.domain.com/v2013/css/sheet.css

THE ANSWER HERE:

FINAL CODE

```
DirectoryIndex v2013/index.html

RewriteEngine On

# exclude files already asking for v2013
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v2013/
RewriteRule ^css/.*$ /v2013/$0
RewriteRule ^js/.*$ /v2013/$0
RewriteRule ^images/.*$ /v2013/$0

RewriteRule ^Bienvenido$ v2013/index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), which rewrites the `css/`, `js/` and `images/` files as well

```
# exclude files already asking for v2013
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v2013/
RewriteRule ^(?:css|images|js)/.*$ /v2013/$0
```

Comment: hey thanks!! you almost got it!... but i need the same for calling images . Do i have to do the same for each folder? EDIT (yes it works)

Answer (score 0):

Where you use the css file don't type "css/style.css", write "/css/style.css". Adding a / takes you to the root. The html should look like this:

```
     <link href="/v2013/css/style.css" rel"stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: your maybe missing the point... 

At this point is looking to www.domain.com/css/sheet.css

If i put /css/ is not going to look at www.domain.com/v2013/css/sheet

Also if you go to domain.com/v2013/index.html my page its looking great its a problem in htaccess so i can show my page on domain.com/welcome